# AngularJS Login/password from json source

Tags: angularjs

i need to creat login form (login/password) and testing login/password from the form with List of login/password in json file 
exemple link:codepen.io/jayeshcp/pen/JXrOgy
i need to change login:admin , password: pass to file json content multi users

Comment: https://codepen.io/jayeshcp/pen/JXrOgy

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] *in the question itself*, **not only on a third-party site**.